# junit @SpringBootTest for org.springframework.cache.Cache

Tags: junit, ehcache, spring-boot-test

I already have spring ehcache in place in a spring-boot application. 1 api is implemented for cache eviction. And I am writing junits for this.

Here is the config code of cacheManager in my Configuration.java

```
 @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager()
    {
            EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
            factoryBean.setShared(true);
            return new EhCacheCacheManager(factoryBean.getObject());
    }
```

In my test class I am not able to mock CacheManager, as not able to read ehcache.xml.

Here is my testClass:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;



@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DriverServiceTest
{

    @InjectMocks
    private DriverServiceImpl driverServiceImpl = null;

    @Mock
    private DriverMongoRepository mongoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager ehCacheManager;

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig
    {
        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager()
        {
            EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
            factoryBean.setShared(true);
            return new EhCacheCacheManager(factoryBean.getObject());
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void testEvictCache() throws Exception
    {
      //Trying to mock ehCacheManager similar to cacheManager() of configuration.java

        String response = driverServiceImpl.evictCache("dummyUser", "getDriver", "1");
    }
}
```

Since my ehCacheManager is not properly mocked, I get null pointer at 
Cache cache =  ehCacheManager.getCache("getDriver");

Can somebody please help me to mock CacheManager similar to cacheManager() of configuration.java

Hope my question is clear!! 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you post you complete code for test case?

Comment: Why are you not able to read the ehcache.xml?

Comment: Can you please remove all commented code and write out your testcase and what you want to assert. Your testcode makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

So here is the sample code for how I achieved caching for ehcache provided by the spring framework.

```
 @SpringBootTest
public class DriverServiceTest
{

    @InjectMocks
    private DriverServiceImpl driverServiceImpl  = null;

    @Mock
    private CacheManager mockCacheManager;

    private static CacheManager cacheManager;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialClassSetUp()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        cacheManager = context.getBean("cacheManager", org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching
    static class SpringConfig
    {
        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager()
        {
            EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
            factoryBean.setShared(true);
            EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
            ehCacheCacheManager.setCacheManager(factoryBean.getObject());
            return ehCacheCacheManager;
        }
    }

   @Test
    public void testEvictCacheKeyNotExist() throws Exception
    {
        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("getSubaccounts");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(driverServiceImpl , "ehCacheManager", cacheManager);
        when(mockCacheManager.getCache(Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(cache);
        String actualValue = driverServiceImpl.evictCache("dummyUserName", "getSubaccounts",
                "dummyKeyName");
        assertTrue(actualValue.equals("key not exists"));
    }
```

Here are the points to note:

1. Need to add the @EnableCaching annotation along with @Configuration on the config static class.
2. The cacheManager value needs to be assigned to the local cacheManager in initialClassSetUp() since it should be done once per class.
3. Now the same cacheManager could be set as the value to the private cachemanager of the service class field by
   ReflectionTestUtils.setField(driverServiceImpl , "ehCacheManager", cacheManager);

And Tada!! now you can assert your cases!!